# How to make css shape on thead tag

Tags: html, css

I want to make a background color with shape on thead tag

like this image

[image]

I try to add border just like a normal shape css, but it's not working

I want to know how to make it work please help.

Comment: Code at which you are stuck ?

Comment: I stuck when I use table It's not working like div tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add following css to take effects

```
th {
        background-color:red;
        border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    }
thead:before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 40px solid white;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: It's working ! but border-left: in th tag is no need to use. However thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform:skew(deg);` property for this below an example

```css
.main {
  width:50%;
  height:40px;
  background:tomato;
  transform:skew(-20deg);
}
.text {
  transform:skew(20deg);
  padding:10px;
}
.main:after {
content: '';
height: 100%;
width: 20px;
display: inline-block;
right: -9px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
transform: skew(20deg);
background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="text">
  Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only start of shape has slope, other is normal

Comment: A liitle explanation wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Use triangle CSS code with white border to achieve that

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  border-left: 20px solid white;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call on a class transparent border, less than the amount you wish for your offset. EX: `border-left: 15px solid transparent;` along with `border-bottom: 30px solid #C50225;`. Add some padding and/or line height, etc... Check out the fiddle I linked below.

[Check out this fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/x9cbLao9/9/)

```css
.myclass {
    padding:10px 10px 10px 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
     
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #C50225; 
     
    height: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.col {
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
<span class="col">P</span>
<span class="col">W</span>
<span class="col">D</span>
<span class="col">L</span>
<span class="col">F</span>
<span class="col">A</span>
<span class="col">GD</span>
<span class="col">Pts</span>
</div>
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Create any shape you want with **[THIS](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)**

I have made a sample for you.

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 280px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 20%, 100% 40%, 0 40%, 15% 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 20%, 100% 40%, 0 40%, 15% 20%);
  /* Center the demo */
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**The above snippet will work in chrome but not in FireFox. Snippet which is working in both browser is given below**

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #b30000;
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#clipping");
  clip-path: url("#clipping");
  /* Center the demo */
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <polygon points="0.07 0, 1 0, 1 1,  0 1" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**UPDATE** : As Justinas found a bug so fixed issue in FireFox.

Comment: `clip-path` does not work on FireFox. In your both examples all I see is blue and red rectangles

Comment: Thank you for telling me. Fixed the issue